# Government sanctioned birth control

Tags: humans, dystopia, medical

The government has recently implementing a law in which you must apply to have children.

To prevent unsanctioned pregnancy and illegal child births they are looking for a way to control when either men or women are fertile.

Would it be possible to prevent either men or women from being fertile in a way that can be temporarily reversed?

Perhaps some sort of implant for women which can be removed by the government controlled doctors and reimplanted after the birth of the child. Similar to the current implant women can have.

Would this be feasible, or is there a better way?

Comment: It looks like you're asking about the current state of reversible long term contraceptive methods.

Comment: Take a look at how China accomplished this.

Comment: Welcome to China. Are you looking for [IUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrauterine_device)s by any chance?

Comment: @AlexP I got mixed up and thought you were talking about [IED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improvised_explosive_device)s for a moment...talk about extreme.... xD

Answer (score 4):

Orally ingested contraceptives have already been developed for both men and women.

The dystopian government can integrate such contraceptives into a centrally controlled food or water supply.

Persons who successfully apply for a reproduction license would be provided with "clean" food and water that has not been laced with the contraceptives. They would continue receiving such supplies for a period of time and in such quantity as determined by the government to be sufficient for pregnancy (the expectant mother would presumably require the clean food/water until the birth of the child, while the father would only need it until impregnation is achieved).

Comment: Or imitate mice sperm and lace it with an abortive substance.

Answer (score 2):

Medically I don't see any reason why not.

There are already a couple different long term reversible contraceptive methods available to women. These include [intrauterine devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrauterine_device), hormonal implants, and hormonal shots.

There is promising research into similar long term methods for men.

It's important to remember that there is a failure rate associated with every birth control method, and that not every birth control method is suitable for all individuals. If the government invested in contraceptive research and worked to pair each individual with the contraceptive method that worked best for them the success rate of such a program could be quite high.

Answer (score 0):

Norplant FTW!!!  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levonorgestrel-releasing_implant

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levonorgestrel-releasing_implant

> It is one of the most effective forms of birth control with a one-year failure rate around 0.05%. The device is placed under the skin and lasts for up to five years.
>
> Following removal fertility quickly returns.
>
> Norplant is implanted under the skin in the upper arm of a woman, by creating a small incision and inserting the capsules in a fanlike shape. Insertion of Norplant usually takes 15 minutes and the capsules can sometimes be seen under the skin, although usually they look like small veins. They can also be felt under the skin. Once inserted, the contraceptive works within 24 hours and lasts up to five years.